# Javascript functions in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, lightning-experience

Can I use standard inbuilt Javascript functions(better lack of words using standard functions) in my client side controller?

I did a search on standard javascript functions and got this as the top link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_builtin_functions.htm

I started playing with some functions and all these functions work as expected.

1) Date

```
var date_v = Date();
component.set("v.date_val",date_v);
```

2) indexof

```
var index = str1.indexOf( "one" );
component.set("v.indexval",index);
```

Does this mean that I can use any JS function in the controller?

Please clarify

Comment: To be pedantic, you should be using `var date_v = new Date()` (don't forget the new).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *most* of the standard JavaScript functions. There are a few that are not implemented for security reasons. You can see what's available and what's not in the [Locker Service API](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV). Several notable examples of things you can't use include ServiceWorker, ShadowRoot, MutationObserver, and a few others. For the day-to-day features that we typically use, like Array, Math, and Date, you'll find that all of those are available as usual.

Comment: Thanks for providing link to locker server api doc, this will be handy guide on checking the supported functions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use any of these functions in lightning. JavaScript is a very mature browser language that has good functions for lot of data manipulations we do.

Always remember that through lightning we manipulate data and it takes care of re-rendering the UI in 99% of the cases(1% left for any custom rendering you may want to do).

You can use all array/object manipulation functions from the below link to do your day to day functions. It also serves as good guide for beginners to use some of the inbuilt functions in javascript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript